# Orthogonal set of a set in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

[image]

This is an exercise in the Folland Real Analysis p.177. I first thought it is an easy one, but it turns out to be a lot trickier.....

I have no idea how to deal with the so-called "double orthogonal set" of E. It is just frustrating...

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a closed subspace of $H$, such that: $E \subset F$.

As $F$ is a closed subspace, we get $F^{\perp \perp} = F$. But:

$E \subset F \implies F^{\perp} \subset E^{\perp} \implies E^{\perp \perp} \subset F^{\perp \perp} = F$

**Edit**: Proving that $F = F^{\perp \perp}$

Note that since $F$ is a closed subspace, and $H$ is a Hilbert, then $H = F \oplus F^{\perp}$.

Let $x \in F^{\perp \perp}$. $x \in H$, so by above, $\exists$ a unique $y \in F$ and a unique $z \in F^{\perp}$ such that: $x = y + z$. Write $z = x - y$. We have that $y \in F \subset F^{\perp \perp}$, but $F^{\perp \perp}$ is a subspace, hence $z \in F^{\perp \perp}$. Thus, $z \in F^{\perp} \cap F^{\perp \perp} = \{0\}$; so that $z = 0$, and $x = y \in F$. The result follows.

Comment: Could you explain about why for a closed subspace F, the equality holds?

Comment: You can prove it by using $F + F^\perp = \mathcal H$.

Comment: @Merideth: Check the edit.